# unable to kill a process using Process.destroy()

Tags: java, process

I'm just experiminting with Runtime and Process classes of java. I'm trying to open a application like windows word using `Runtime.exec()` and then waiting some time and trying to destroy it using `Process.destroy()` method.
 MS Word is opening but it's not closing throwing below exception in console

```
exception::java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException: current thread not owner
```

Below is my code

```
 import java.util.*;

public class StringTesting {

    public void open()
    {

        try{
        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();

        Process proc =runtime.exec("C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Office\\Office12\\winword.exe");

        StringTesting st = new StringTesting();

        st.wait(5000);

        // now destroy the process

         proc.destroy();
         System.out.println("  after destroy");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(" exception::"+e);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String a[])
    {
        StringTesting st = new StringTesting();
          st.open();  
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that you cannot invoke `Object.wait()` without holding the monitor for that object:

```
StringTesting st = new StringTesting();
synchronized (st) {
    st.wait(5000);
}
```